# Rails Routes - How to get nested IDs from URI Pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

In my router I have nested two ressources:

```
resources :servers do
  member do
    resources :maintenances
  end
end
```

which results in URI pattern as follows:

```
         maintenance GET    /servers/:id/maintenances/:id(.:format)      maintenances#show
```

In maintenance_controller's show action I want to get these IDs like:

```
@server = Server.find_by(params[:id])
@maintenance = Maintenance.find_by ???
```

My Question is: How can I access these two IDs in my maintenance_controller from the URI pattern http://localhost/servers/1/maintenances/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
resources :servers do
  resources :maintenances
end
```

Then you can access the nested resource as follow

```
server_maintenance GET    /servers/:server_id/maintenances/:id(.:format)
```

In your controller

```
@server = Server.find(params[:server_id])
@maintenance = Maintenance.find(params[:id])
```

The complete documentation about routing in rails is in the [official docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)